# How to provide following access on object records NOT owned by the user (OWD is private): Edit access on some fields and read access on some fields

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, owd, criteria-based-sharing

I have following scneario regarding an object

1. OWD is private
2. For record that are not owned by user, they should be able to have read access on some fields and write access on some fields.

I have tried the following:
Created sharing settings and assigned to a public group. But the issue is that with this approach I can either give read access to all the fields or RW access to all the fields.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** :
After getting the exact requirement (refer comments section), the scenario in the question cannot be implemented using out of the box Salesforce functionality.

Comment: How will permission set solve the issue ? For the records that the user owns, user has edit access on all the fields. So, if I give Read access to other's record using sharing setting, all fields will be read-only. Similarly, So, if I give RW access to other's record using sharing setting, all fields will be RW.

Comment: No , If user does not get edit access to field via profile or permission set , field remains read-only even if user becomes the owner of the record. Also , your question states "access for records now owned by the user" . I assume "now" is "not"

Comment: With permission sets , you can control access at both object & field level. Hence , the solution. And of course , we are not considering special permissions like "view all" & "modify all"

Comment: I guess you edited your comment. And you mean "sharing rule" instead of "sharing setting".

Comment: Right. The question is access for records not owned by the user.

Comment: So, take a simple scenario. User has Edit access to all the fields of the record it owns. And since OWD is private, user cannot see other's record.
When I open up access using public group and sharing rule, I can either give Read access to ALL fields or RW access to ALL fields. How will PS solve the issue ? Can you explain by giving example ?

Comment: First thing which we need to specify is - How does the user have edit access to all fields?  We need to remove that access and then introduce permission sets. We can then define access for each field individually. Also , why is it that you can only give Read or RW to ALL fields ?  If user already has read or RW for all fields then no mechanism can decrease that access...

Comment: User needs edit access to all the fields of the record HE OWNS. But for other records that user does not own, when access is opened up using public group/sharing rules, business wants some fields read only and some field editable. I guess this is not possible currently.

Comment: Exactly , your question can be updated with above sentence. It completely changes the question :)

Comment: Thank you @Avinash , I updated my answer.